# How to refresh Service ACL for job.submission.protocol.acl in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, authorization, acl

I am using Cloudera's CDH distribution of Hadoop and have recently upgraded from CDH3 to CDH4.

In CDH3 I used to be able to add user names into **hadoop-policy.xml** for:

> security.client.protocol.acl
>
> security.job.submission.protocol.acl

And then run:

```
hadoop dfsadmin -refreshServiceAcl

hadoop mradmin -refreshServiceAcl
```

And, voila, the user could access HDFS and run MR jobs.

Now adding first user since upgrading to CDH4 and it looks like something has changed.

Still adding user to same in **hadoop-policy.xml** as above.
For HDFS access I run:

```
hdfs dfsadmin -refreshServiceAcl
```

However, I cannot figure out what is appropriate to give user access to "security.job.submission.protocol.acl".
When I run:

```
hadoop mradmin -refreshServiceAcl
```

I get:

> DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute mapred command is
>   deprecated. Instead use the mapred command for it. refreshServiceAcl:
>   java.io.IOException: Unknown protocol:
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.RefreshAuthorizationPolicyProtocol

And of course user gets:

> org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException: User
>   username (auth:SIMPLE) is not authorized for protocol interface
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobSubmissionProtocol, expected client
>   Kerberos principal is null

I have not installed YARN/MRv2 and "/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/bin/mapred" is just a soft link to "/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/bin/hadoop".

Any idea how I can update the JobSubmissionProtocol to accept the new user?

Comment: I can update the Service Level Authorization for security.job.submission.protocol.acl by restarting the JobTracker. However, I would like to be able to do this without a service restart. Is there any way to refreshServiceAcl for security.job.submission.protocol.acl?

Answer (score 2):

`hadoop-policy.xml` file in `hadoop_home/conf` directory contains all security-related settings.  I believe you need to add user name in property settings.  See below:

```
<property>
<name>security.job.submission.protocol.acl</name>
<value>*</value>
<description>
ACL for jobsubmissionProtocol, used by job clients to communicate with the job tracker 
for job submission, kill etc. The ACL is a comma separated list of user and group name. 
The user and grouplist is separated by a blank. For e.g., "majeed, john, developers,testers". 
A special value of "*" means all users are allowed. </description>
</property>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think ...

**MapReducePolicyProvider.java** use 
import org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.RefreshAuthorizationPolicyProtocol;

**MRAdmin.java** use 
import org.apache.hadoop.mr1security.authorize.RefreshAuthorizationPolicyProtocol;

this mismatching causes of error.

But I don't know why using different class for each file.